# What authorization is needed to upgrade an AKS cluster?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, rbac

I am trying to update my Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) cluster with the following command:

```
az aks upgrade \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name myAKSCluster \
    --kubernetes-version KUBERNETES_VERSION
```

This results in the following response:

> (AuthorizationFailed) The client '>email<' with object id '>object id<' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/write' over scope '/subscriptions/>id</resourceGroups/>resourcegroup-name</providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters/>cluster-name<' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.
> Code: AuthorizationFailed

When I go to resourcegroup/Access Control(IAM), I find these roles assigned to me when I click on "view my access"

[IAM access control roles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/080s6.png)

These are:

```
Azure Kubernetes Service Cluster Admin Role
List cluster admin credential action.
--
Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Cluster Admin
Lets you manage all resources in the cluster.
--
Reader
View all resources, but does not allow you to make any changes.
--
Storage Account Contributor
Lets you manage storage accounts, including accessing storage account keys which prov...
```

I would expect that having the role "Azure Kubernetes Service RBAC Cluster Admin" that says:
"Lets you manage all resources in the cluster." would authorize me to upgrade the cluster to a new version.

I run into the same problem when trying to create a static IP-adress via the Microsoft documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Created Kubernetes cluster with 1.24 version when I run the same command got the same error:

```yaml
az aks upgrade \
    --resource-group myResourceGroup \
    --name myAKSCluster \
    --kubernetes-version KUBERNETES_VERSION
```

[image: ![enter image description here](https://i.imgur.com/1xgaXsy.png)]

To resolve this issue, make sure to add **`Contributor`** role to the user in subscription level.

[image]

Now when I run the below command got result successfully:

```
az aks upgrade --resource-group <RGName> --name <myAKSCluster> --kubernetes-version 1.25
```

[image]

```
agentPoolProfiles": [
    {
      "availabilityZones": [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
      ],
      "count": 1,
      "creationData": null,
      "currentOrchestratorVersion": "1.25.6",
      "enableAutoScaling": true,
      "enableEncryptionAtHost": null,
      "enableFips": false,
      "enableNodePublicIp": false,
      "enableUltraSsd": null,
      "gpuInstanceProfile": null,
      "hostGroupId": null,
      "kubeletConfig": null,
      "kubeletDiskType": "OS",
      "linuxOsConfig": null,
```

In portal:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!! Is there any way to get the same level authorization as the "owner" role, without having the owner role?